# Unable to load images from the URL

Tags: android

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  int mCurrentPage;
  Context c;
  GridView mListView;
  String id, cat;
  String strUrl;
  TextView tvtitle;
  TextView tv_id, tv_rating, tv_url;
  public static String img_url, img_rating, img_id, img_name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starters, container, false);
    tv_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id);
    tv_rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf);
    tv_url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url);
    cat = Category.Main_Cat;
    Log.i("Logcat Cat1", cat);
    switch (mCurrentPage) {
    case 1:
        Log.v("MyFragment Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        Log.i("Cat IS", Category.Main_Cat);
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        break;
    }
    return v;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }

}

private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {
    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }
        StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;
        try {
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        String[] from = { "poster", "year", "duration", "id", "title" };
        int[] to = { R.id.iv_flag, R.id.tv_starter_hide_url,
                R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf, R.id.tv_starter_hide_id,
                R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
                .getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getActivity());
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                    .getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
            ImageView posterImage=((ImageView)adapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.iv_flag));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(imgUrl, R.drawable.empty_photo, posterImage);
            //ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);
    //      imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);*/
        }
    }
}

private class ImageLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(
            HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream = null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory
            File cacheDirectory = getActivity().getBaseContext()
                    .getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"
                    + position + ".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

            // Close the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position
            // in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("flag", tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position", position);

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and
            // position
            return hmBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        String path = (String) result.get("flag");

        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the
        // listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                .getItem(position);

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
        hm.put("flag", path);

        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

In my application
My images URL are showing in `LogCat` but unable to display the images and its temporary image is also not displaying. What should i do to make it work? Share your suggestion. thank you. :-)

1.Device image
[image: Here is the image]

2.Logcat image
[image]

Comment: @satishkumar. what i do....

Comment: Check Whether you have added     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in your manifest. The above is not a good practice of showing images. Use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Lazy Loader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). It will handle all of your problems

Comment: @RethinavelPillai thankyou but i have tried that

Comment: It should work. Universal image loader has some standards. What have you tried? Share your tried code!! Let's check them.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai i am editing my cod ewith image loader.....

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha it has been closed from so many time .it is not live now

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha there is no problem now ...:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you writing your own code for downloading images,

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Here is library, It will download you images from url, assign them to imageviews, and will also cache images, When you demand for image in future, It will search in local cache and provide to your application without downloading again and again.